# Spring mvc: Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I have two tables `Employee` and `Address` as shown:

```
public class Employee {

    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean employeeStatus;
    private Address address;

        //getters setters
    }

public class Address {
    private Integer id;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private Integer emp_id;
    //getters setters
    }


@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     @Autowired
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
         public void insertEmployee(Employee e)
         {
         String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_employee (dept_id,firstName,lastName,employeeStatus) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
         this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,new
                 Object[]{e.getDept_id(),e.getFirstName(),e.getLastName(),e.isEmployeeStatus()});


// INSERT ADDRESS????
         }

   // Other Methods
        }
```

Now i want to implement `Transactional` while inserting the `employee`  and `address` table attributes. I am abit confused here. Does `@transactional` annotation over the method does the required job? So far i understood that. Also, is it best practice to insert address from where i am inserting `employee` attributes? I also read somewhere that the transactional should be implemented from service layer than Dao. How would transactional can be implemented in this case?

**EDIT** 
Since it is recommended to use `@transactional` in service layer, service layer became like:

```
@Service("employeeService")
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;
    @Autowired
    AddressDao addressDao;

    @Override
    public void insertEmployee(Employee e) {
        employeeDao.insertEmployee(e);
        addressDao.insertAddress(e.address);

    }
}
```

is it the right way to perform transactional? Also can anyone explain `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)` instead of plain @Transactional ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alltough the @Transactional annotation would do the job, transactions are usually defined on service level. This way one business call is in one transaction, making sure everything succeeds or fails together.

you can read about @transactional in combination with jdbctemplate [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.be/2007/03/spring-jdbctemplate-and-transactions.html)

Comment: I did a edit. Can you look at it and make a comment if it is the way it should be?

Comment: looks good, Propagation supports means that if a transaction allready exists, that transaction shall be used. so if you have a service calling another service, they still only use one transaction. Readonly should be set to true if no modificatons happen in that service call. Some databases are able to optimise their locking behaviour due to this flag.